# How to debug failing service in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, services

I have a application which i can run without any problems as a normal application. The application is using I2C and WiFi. I can detect the data flow through wireshark so i can confirm that it is actually functioning. The moment i implement it as a service it is crashing after a while without any useable error than the one below. Is there a way to get a stacktrace or anything in order to debug it?

```
* comi2c.service - I2C master
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/comi2c.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2015-03-13 16:15:14 CET; 1min 4s ago
  Process: 195 ExecStart=//home/sandbox/main 192.168.0.142 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

    Mar 13 15:40:56 sandbox systemd[1]: comi2c.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
    Mar 13 15:40:56 sandbox systemd[1]: Failed to start I2C master.
    Mar 13 15:40:56 sandbox systemd[1]: Unit salto.service entered failed state.
    Mar 13 15:40:56 sandbox systemd[1]: comi2c.service failed.
```

The service:

```
[Unit]
Description=I2C master

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/root/run-i2cmaster.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the run-i2cmaster.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

export $SENDER = 192.168.0.142

/home/sandbox/main $SENDER
```

**UPDATE**

If i change the type from `forking` to `simple` it seems to solve the problem. Which i don't understand why?

Comment: Does `/home/sandbox/main` actually fork? If not, you need to change the type from `forking` to `simple`. Also, there is no reason to use the shell script, you can do all of that from the unit file.

Comment: It does fork, and it actually runs, but it dies after a while. I tried to do it directly without the SH file, but the result was still the same. `root       226 98.6  0.2   4584  2164 ?        Rs   16:40   0:37 /home/sandbox/main 192.168.0.142
`, it seems to be running. And i am receiving data from both ends.

Comment: I have updated my post. It seems that when i change the type from `forking` to `simple` it is running without crashing? I assume that i am using the wrong type as my application is just looping until it is stopped..